# Batteries in parallel

Tags: batteries, resistors

What will happen if 2 or more ideal batteries with different emfs are connected in parallel across a resistor?

Just curious to know what folk around here think..

Comment: Theoretically or practically?

Comment: what's an "emfs"?

Comment: EMF = Electro Motive Force - sometimes used erroneously in place of voltage.

Answer (score 5):

In ideal circuit theory, connecting two ideal constant voltage sources (batteries) in parallel (using ideal wires of course) results in a *contradiction*.

For example, a 1V and 2V voltage source in parallel, yields by KVL:

$$1V = 2V$$

There are many ways to draw an *inconsistent* circuit in ideal circuit theory so this shouldn't be particularly mysterious.

One might say that the current that circulates through the ideal voltage sources is 'infinite' thus producing a non-zero voltage across the ideal wire but that's no better, in my opinion, than saying that the circuit is inconsistent.

Of course, physical voltage sources can't produce arbitrarily large current thus, the missing circuit elements are the series ideal resistors that model the limited short-circuit current of the voltage sources and the resistance of the connecting wires.

Ideal circuit elements are used to *model* physical circuit elements and we must not forget to include the appropriate elements to account for the non-ideal characteristics.

Answer (score 3):

You'll let the magic smoke out.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke

Comment: Don't worry, you can put it back in again: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10622

Answer (score 1):

When two ideal batteries of different voltages are connected together and the connection is also ideal, then Infinite current will flow from battery with higher voltage rating to the other. The resulting voltage across this connection can not be determined.

Connecting a resistor in parallel will not cause any change to this condition.

Answer (score 0):

POP - BOOM - BANG ! ! !   The higher voltage battery will try to charge the lower voltage battery.  There will be a high current draw from the higher voltage battery.  You will get thermal run-a-way and POP - BOOM - BANG !   You will be spending more money.

Side Note:  If both batteries are the same voltage (as close as can be under normal conditions) - Example: Two Car Batteries in Parallel as when getting a Jump Start.  There is no Voltage problem - Yet - There can be a Very High current draw from  one batter to the other.  Another issue is internal resistance of the batteries.  There can be a huge drop in voltage.
Another Side Note:  When running two batteries in parallel the batteries should be of different AH (Amp Hours).  The reason for this is Charging.  They both will not reach FULL Charge because to the source voltage they will LOOK like they are at full charge.  By keeping them at different AH ratings the lower AH battery will reach charge first BUT!  The higher AH battery will still be calling for a charge.  The Delta in the AH rating should be 10%.